# Trying to convert USD to GB in price.html, only working on first product

Tags: magento-1.9, currency

I need USD prices to convert to pounds for users that are logged in with their billing address in the UK. The code below works but only on the first product. I'm probably missing something obvious here?

The file is located in \default\template\catalog\product\price.phtml

```
<?php 
        $session = Mage::getSingleton('customer/session');
        if ($session->isLoggedIn()) {
            $countryCode = $session->getCustomer()->getDefaultBillingAddress()->getCountry();
            $usdPrice = Mage::helper('core')->currency($_product->getFinalPrice(),false);


            if($countryCode == "GB") {

                 if(!function_exists(convertCurrencyGb)) {

                     function convertCurrencyGb($amount, $from, $to){
                        $data = file_get_contents("https://finance.google.com/finance/converter?a=$amount&from=$from&to=$to");
                        preg_match("/<span class=bld>(.*)<\/span>/",$data, $converted);
                        $converted = preg_replace("/[^0-9.]/", "", $converted[1]);
                        return number_format(round($converted, 3),2);
                    }
                    $newprice = convertCurrencyGb($usdPrice, "USD", "GBP");
                 }

                echo ' <div class="test" style="display: none;">';
                echo $newprice;
                echo '</div>';
            }
        }
    ?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think `$newprice = convertCurrencyGb($usdPrice, "USD", "GBP");` should be outside the statement`if(!function_exists(convertCurrencyGb)) {`  .

Move it below the curly bracket that is below it now.